# Conflict between two js scripts, I can't understand why?

Tags: javascript, conflict

I am trying to implement a tracking script that standalone and on other sites works just as intended (or atleast to what I can see from watching the sites and analytics).

The code looks like this

```
 {
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var filetypes = /\.(zip|exe|dmg|pdf|doc.*|xls.*|ppt.*|mp3|txt|rar|wma|mov|avi|wmv|flv|wav)$/i;
    var baseHref = '';
    if (jQuery('base').attr('href') != undefined) baseHref = jQuery('base').attr('href');

    jQuery('a').on('click', function(event) {
      var el = jQuery(this);
      var track = true;
      var href = (typeof(el.attr('href')) != 'undefined' ) ? el.attr('href') :"";
      var isThisDomain = href.match(document.domain.split('.').reverse()[1] + '.' + document.domain.split('.').reverse()[0]);
      if (!href.match(/^javascript:/i)) {
        var elEv = []; elEv.value=0, elEv.non_i=false;
        if (href.match(/^mailto\:/i)) {
          elEv.category = "Email";
          elEv.action = "Klick";
          elEv.label = href.replace(/^mailto\:/i, '');
          elEv.loc = href;
        }
        else if (href.match(filetypes)) {
          var extension = (/[.]/.exec(href)) ? /[^.]+$/.exec(href) : undefined;
          elEv.category = "Nerladdning";
          elEv.action = "Fil-" + extension[0];
          elEv.label = href.replace(/ /g,"-");
          elEv.loc = baseHref + href;
        }
        else if (href.match(/^https?\:/i) && !isThisDomain) {
          elEv.category = "Ex.Länk";
          elEv.action = "Klick";
          elEv.label = href.replace(/^https?\:\/\//i, '');
          elEv.non_i = true;
          elEv.loc = href;
        }

        else track = false;

        if (track) {
          _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', elEv.category.toLowerCase(), elEv.action.toLowerCase(), elEv.label.toLowerCase(), elEv.value, elEv.non_i]);
          if ( el.attr('target') == undefined || el.attr('target').toLowerCase() != '_blank') {
            setTimeout(function() { location.href = elEv.loc; }, 400);
            return false;
      }
    }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

This is the jquery version that is loaded before

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Now onto the problem, if I place "my" script above the ones I will post below then my script works. But if I do it as I want, placing my script last on the page it does not work, or anywhere aslong as it is below the other one will end up with mine not working

```
<script type="text/javascript"> jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { runJS(); }); </script>
```

The runJS leads to another .js file that is functions.js, of what I can understand runJS is this (I replaced the name of the site with site below).

```
function runJS() {

    if((fontLoaded('DistrictThin') && fontLoaded('NationalLight')) || timer > 30) {
        site.init();

        $(".search_result").find('img').load(function () {
            $(".search_result.primary").equalHeights();
            //$(".search_result:not(.primary)").equalHeights();
        });        

        if ($('#site_search_form').length > 0) {
            populateForm();
        }
    }
    else {
        setTimeout('runJS()', 100);
        timer += 1; 
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: are you using two type of jquery version

Answer (score 0):

if you using different version of jquery in single page you must use this

```
   var jq = jQuery.noConflict (); // jq having the value of $.
                                 // In your entire script use jq instead of $.
```

Comment: This is in the header

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[ !window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="/ui/scripts/jquery.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E')); //]]></script>`

This is in the footer

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

Is that what you mean?